# Linear Transformation with different base

Tags: linear-algebra

In this exercise: Let $V$ be the subspace of $R[x]$ spanned by $1, x, x^2, x^3$, let $W:=\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $f: V\to W$ be defined by $f(p) := (p(1), p(2), p(3))$

I have to determine the matrix corresponding to $f$ with respect to the bases: $1, x, x^2, x^3$ for $V$ and $(1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 3), (1, 4, 9)$ for $W$.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 & -6\\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 6\\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm not remotely sure if this is correct, appreciate any help

Comment: How did you get the third column?

Comment: by (at least) trying to solve for f(x^3) a linear equation

Comment: The third column consists of numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $f(x^3) = a(1,1,1)+b(1,2,3)+c(1,4,9)$. I think you made a mistake in the computations.

Comment: yeah, I'm still getting weird solutions, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is not correct. I have found
\begin{align}
f(1)&=(1,1,1)=1(1,1,1)+0(1,2,3)+0(1,4,9);\\
f(x)&=(1,2,3)=0(1,1,1)+1(1,2,3)+0(1,4,9);\\
f(x^2)&=(1,4,9)=0(1,1,1)+0(1,2,3)+1(1,4,9);\\
f(x^3)&=(1,8,27)=6(1,1,1)-11(1,2,3)+6(1,4,9).
\end{align}
Therefore,$$M(f)=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 6\\
 0 & 1 & 0 & -11\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 6
\end{pmatrix}.$$